# Need to extract column title if value exists in a 2d array in microsoft excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this 2d array table (image attached-table 1).

[image: table 1]

I want to extract column names for all tags which are marked with "x". For eg: For Tag 1, I want the values A and G returned. Similarly, for Tag 2, A, C and F should be returned. How should I do it in excel?

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Do you want the answers as a comma-separated list??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$H$1,0,SMALL(IF(INDIRECT("$A$"&SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$5=B$7,ROW($A$1:$A$5)),1)&":$H$"&SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$5=B$7,ROW($A$1:$A$5)),1))="X",COLUMN($A$1:$H$1)),ROW(1:1))),"")}
```

You can then drag that down and across for all other rows. Assuming your data starts in A1, here is what it looks like:

[image: .]

Comment: Thank you. This gave me the list as per my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

in **I2** enter:

```
=MID(IF(B2="x","," & $B$1,"") & IF(C2="x","," & $C$1,"") & IF(D2="x","," & $D$1,"") & IF(E2="x","," & $E$1,"") & IF(F2="x","," & $F$1,"") & IF(G2="x","," & $G$1,"") &  IF(H2="x","," & $H$1,""),2,99)
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I wanted a list like the below answer. However, this helped in another way. :)